# Cannot change NTP Time Source on a 2012 R2 DC Server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ntp, clock-synchronization

So I have seen dozens of people with this issue on various websites and forums, but here I am asking again. No matter what I try so far, nothing has fixed the issue which I will describe below in as much detail as I can.

To start, the server is running `Windows Server 2012 R2` and is the only server on the network.
(Customer refuses to update to new equipment, no hate please.)
It is the DC and runs a program called ChiroTouch for the business which has around 10-15 computers.

Now everything works as well as it can, except the server suffers from moderate to severe clock drift. The system clock is slowly drifting further ahead and at the time of posting is around 2 minutes off. Its not always the same amount of time out of sync, but usually hovers around 1-3 minutes off. Worst I've seen was 15 minutes ahead at one point.

Now, when I check the time source, it says Local CMOS Clock and nothing I have tried has made it look at an external NTP source.

**Here are the fixes I have tried so far:**

-Changed Time Provider type from NTP to NT5D5 and back again.

-Changed NTP registry entries to recommended values manually.

-Unregistered and registered w32tm.

-Manually set time source using `w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:"pool.ntp.org" /syncfromfla gs:manual /reliable:yes /update`

-Checked Group Policy for any rogue Windows Time entries on the domain or local computer.

During every one of those attempts I perform the appropriate w32tm starts, stops, and resyncs and then check the w32tm source and it still says Local CMOS Clock.

Also, here is the output of `w32tm /query /configuration`:

```
[Configuration]

EventLogFlags: 2 (Local)
AnnounceFlags: 5 (Local)
TimeJumpAuditOffset: 28800 (Local)
MinPollInterval: 6 (Local)
MaxPollInterval: 10 (Local)
MaxNegPhaseCorrection: 172800 (Local)
MaxPosPhaseCorrection: 172800 (Local)
MaxAllowedPhaseOffset: 300 (Local)

FrequencyCorrectRate: 4 (Local)
PollAdjustFactor: 5 (Local)
LargePhaseOffset: 50000000 (Local)
SpikeWatchPeriod: 900 (Local)
LocalClockDispersion: 10 (Local)
HoldPeriod: 5 (Local)
PhaseCorrectRate: 7 (Local)
UpdateInterval: 100 (Local)


[TimeProviders]

NtpClient (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\system32\w32time.DLL (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMinutes: 15 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMaxTimes: 7 (Local)
CompatibilityFlags: 2147483648 (Local)
EventLogFlags: 1 (Local)
LargeSampleSkew: 3 (Local)
SpecialPollInterval: 3600 (Local)
Type: NTP (Local)
NtpServer: pool.ntp.org (Local)

NtpServer (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\system32\w32time.DLL (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 0 (Local)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)

VMICTimeProvider (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\System32\vmictimeprovider.dll (Local)
Enabled: 0 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
```

As you can see, it claims that the NTP source is pool.ntp.org, but when you actually run the query command it says Local CMOS Clock and all resync attempts fail.

Now I have a couple theories that I can't confirm, but maybe someone else can.

1. Chirotouch is for some reason causing the issue.
2. 2012 R2 is just too old to care at this point.

Any ideas or solutions are welcome.

Comment: To clarify, those configuration results are what shows up right after I unregister and register.

Comment: Is the server a VM?

Comment: No VMs on the network, only the main DC which is a physical machine onsite.

Answer (score 0):

What if you  `net stop w32time && net start w32time`
just after manually set your time source , and then querying again ?

Comment: Tried that as well, same outcome as the rest.